# How to separate the components tree. And move it to the right. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to separate the "Component Tree". And move it to the right. Android Studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYFv.png)

How to return as it was before?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found solution for that.
But, at least, you can attach `Pallete & Component Tree` view to the right side:

[image]

Or you can activate `Floating mode` and place where it is suitable for you:

[image]

Comment: How to share on NI Palette from Component Tree